# Smartcard ef.sod retrieve data eID epassports

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, asn.1, pkcs#7, pcsc

I am trying to do passive authentication after reading ef.sod from smartcard. Unfortunately, I don't know how to read data from the ef.sod file, such as:

- the Document Signer Certificate (CDS)
- the Document Signer signature
- hashes from the relevant Data Groups

In my understanding, first of all, I must:

- read the ef.sod file from the smartcard
- retreive the DS certificate, DS signature and hash data groups (DG) from the ef.sod file.
- extract the public key from the DS certificate and use it to decrypt the DS signature
- the result of decryption (hash) compare with the hash ef.sod that I need to create
- finally compare the DG hashes extracted from ef.sod with the hashes created from individual DGs

So far I was able to read the ef.sod in hex form. I tried to parse ef.sod with ASN1 decoders, but none of the on-line decoders can parse ef.sod file.

Is there any tool (libraries) that can decompose ef.sod and perform passive auth to check validity of stored data.

Please provide some approach, thanks in advance.